# How to interpret $|z-c|$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to interpret the expression 
$$|z-c|, z \in \mathbb{C}$$?

I'm thinking,

$$|z-c|=|a+bi-c|=|(a+c)+bi|=|w|$$

and then one can apply more rules to the simpler expression $|w|$, $w \in \mathbb{C}$.

Is this the way?

What I'm confused about is how to interpret the positive and negative $z$s (or $a$s in $|a|$), like one has to do with real absolute values.

That is,

Knowing that these two complex numbers have the same absolute value:
[image]

How does it  affect the interpretation of the expression?
Does it mean that $|z-c|$ is "two-sided" geometrically?

Comment: So $c\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @AdamFrancey Well, the complex addition rules would be found for $c \in \mathbb{R}$ as well? It's the absolute value I'm confused about.

Comment: It is the distance between $z$ and $c$ in the complex plane, if that's what you mean by "interpret".

Comment: @mlainz So it's just like a typical modulus? I was confused by the real equivalent of this kind of expression, which involves checking for positive and negative "parts".

Comment: If $c\in \mathbb{C}$, why don't you break apart $c$ into its real and imaginary components like you did with $z$?

Comment: @AdamFrancey Well you could do that?

Comment: If $z=a+bi$, $c=a'+bi'$, then $|z-c|=\sqrt{(a-a')^2+(b-b')^2}$. Does that help you?

Comment: These two complex numbers have the same absolute value: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/Complex_conjugate_picture.svg/220px-Complex_conjugate_picture.svg.png

Answer (score 4):

$|z-c|$ is simply the distance between the points $z$ and $c$ on the complex plane. Now $w=z-c$ is a complex number, so $|z-c|=|w|$ is also the distance between $w$ and the origin.

Comment: It's not the distance of $w=z-c$ from the origin?

Comment: @mavavilj in "vector" language, $z-c$ would be the vector and $|z-c|$ the length.

Answer (score 0):

$|z-c|$ is the distance from $z$ to $c.$ For example, the set of $z\in \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $|z-c|=1$ is the circumference of center $c$ and radius $1.$ Of course, if you write $w=z-c$ then you are doing a translation: you are movin $c$ to the origin. Thus, you can interpret $|w|$ as the distance from the origin to $w.$